# Which software(s) can serve as Mathematica, Maple or MATLAB equivalents?

Tags: software-recommendation, matlab, mathematica

I'd like to know the equivalents of Mathematica, Maple, or MATLAB on Ubuntu, since all are costly.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Octave](http://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) provides a lot of the functionality of Matlab, and can run some Matlab programs.  [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/) is the open source "equivalent" of Mathematica.

Comment: Good answer, gets straight to the point. GNU Octave is pretty good, although, yeah I would like to see a GUI made for it. Sage can also be used to perform numerical computations. It's the fusion of GNU Octave, MATLAB, Scilab, Numpy, Scipy, Maple, Mathematica and other mathematics software written in a common python programming language.

Answer (score 6):

I use QT Octave as GNU Octave does not have a nice GUI. Though most of the commands work out pretty well, some functions may not work as expected in MATLAB

Comment: I strongly recommend QT Octave, or called from C++ (which I have also been experimenting with).

Answer (score 4):

[Reduce](http://reduce-algebra.sourceforge.net/), [Maxima](http://maxima.sourceforge.net/), [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org/), [Axiom](http://www.axiom-developer.org/) (in three variations), and others, all are free and will provide you computer algebra on Linux.

Answer (score 4):

You can also give [R](http://www.r-project.org/) a try.
It is an open-source, free, programming environment. It has both powerful visualization capabilities, power numerical libraries, and everything you would expect from a functional programming language (well, except a compiler).

Comment: If you want to use R, I recommend looking at RStudio ( http://rstudio.org/ ), which has an interface which should be familiar to a MATLAB user. It isn't in the Ubuntu repositories but you can download a .deb package from their website.

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest **python** with appropriate libraries as a good option.

It is not quite a replacement, since the python language is not as specialised for mathematics as matlab/mathematica syntax, but it combines a relatively good syntax for interactive mathematics with a fully-capable programming language.

You will want to install the packages:

- `ipython` - a much nicer version of the standard python shell, with session saving, tab-completion, etc. See their [website](https://ipython.org/). You might also want `ipython-notebook` which provides a browser-based interactive session (see image below).

[image: ipython notebook]

- `python-numpy python-scipy python-matplotlib` - Core scientific python libraries; [Numpy](https://numpy.org/) provides efficient arrays for handling large amounts of data; [Scipy](https://scipy.org/) provides algorithms, eg clustering, FFT, numerical integration, linear algebra; and [Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) provides a wide variety of plotting functions (including an interface designed for interactive use).
- `spyder` - I normally just use these libraries with a text editor and a ipython terminal session, but if you are more comfortable with an integrated environment you may look at [spyder](https://www.spyder-ide.org/), an IDE designed in the vein of matlab/mathematica using the above libraries. See screenshot below.

[image: spyder screenshot]

Answer (score 2):

[Freemat](http://freemat.sourceforge.net/) is a good alternative. It can handle most of the Matlab m-scripts.

Comment: Eh, not really -- FreeMat is rarely updated. The latest version available in the software centre was released 2008.

Answer (score 1):

Both Mathematica and Matlab are very bloated as they try to do too much and be sort of a silver bullet. As I said, they try.

Most open source libraries and tools however, focus on a particular problem or domain area and do it the best and fastest way, while making sure that they import and export to appropriate formats so you can work with several different tools and pass your data from one to another.

You will likely receive much more useful response to your question by specifying the specific domain you want to work in, or the specific type of tools you need as opposed to trying to find a clone of something like Matlab, which I wouldn't use even if it was free.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest installing Cantor which supports four different environments (Maxima, R, SAGE and KAlgebra).

```
sudo apt-get install cantor
```

It has a very simple interface and it is easy to use.
[image: Cantor main window]

Answer (score 0):

I have several suggestions:

1. For some users, [xcas](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geogebra) can also be an option. It has a general purpose computer algebra system and a graphical user interface. There is also a [web version](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Installation#GeoGebra_Classic_5_for_Desktop) available.
2. GeoGebra is also an option. You can use the old unmaintained [version 4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=geogebra) which has no restrictions for commercial use, or download either [version 5](https://wiki.geogebra.org/en/Reference:GeoGebra_Installation#GeoGebra_Classic_5_for_Desktop) from GeoGebra's official website (this package is currently unsupported), or [version 6](https://flathub.org/apps/org.geogebra.GeoGebra) as a community maintained Flathub package. Eventually, you can try [GeoGebra Discovery](https://kovzol.github.io/geogebra-discovery) (maintained by me) which is a fork of GeoGebra 5 with some additional experimental features. These versions can be used only under certain [conditions](https://www.geogebra.org/license). 
   If it is acceptable for you to use an online version of GeoGebra, you can simply visit its [official website](https://www.geogebra.org). It works on all major platforms and has more or less the same features as version 6.
3. If you need only the command line version of Mathematica (*Wolfram Engine for Developers*, also known as *Wolfram Engine Community Edition*), it is available for developers free of charge: https://www.wolfram.com/developer/, https://www.wolfram.com/engine/faq/.